# How to handle very big numbers in node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, numbers, biginteger

I am using BigInt(20) datatype for auto Increment id in mysql database.
and when the integer value is so big then how can I handle this as after the number precision of javascript, it won't to allow to insert and read any number Value. So how can I achieve this.
Read about the big-integer libraries but I won't the expected result

Example:-

```
var x = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
```

How can I print the same number without using its exponential value and any garbage value ?

I tried like that

```
var BigNumber = require('big-number');

var x = new BigNumber(999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 10);
console.log(x);
```

Example2:-

If I get the last inserted Id, then how can I handle this value

```
 connection_db.query('INSERT INTO tableName SET ?', tableData, 
  function (error1, results1, fields1) {
     error1){
         // Db error
        }else{
         var lastInserted = new BigNumber(results1.insertId);
         console.log(lastInserted);// still wrong value
          }

  });
```

Comment: Don't think BIGINT(20) generates a int with 20 digits.. the (20) only apply to zerofull function of mysql... the minimal and maximal values off BIGINT are here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html..

Comment: @robertklep provides a good answer. I want to add another thought. Depending on your concrete environment, JavaScript gives you "safe integers" up to 2^53 - 1. MySQL's BIGINT is (depending on your installation) a 64 bit value. So, if 2^53 - 1 (= 9007199254740991) is enough for your needs, you might use this combination anyway (taking care of your bounds, of course).

Answer (score 3):

You can only pass/show large numbers like that as *strings*:

```
var BigNumber = require('big-number');

var x = new BigNumber('999999999999999999999999999999999999999', 10);
console.log(x.toString())
```

However, in the end, it's up to the MySQL driver how it handles large numbers like this, because it does have to take into account [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

For instance, the [`mysql`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) module has various options (`supportBigNumbers` and `bigNumberStrings`) that relate to handling `BIGINT`.

Comment: It's worth clarifying:  If your application requires integer values with more than 14 or 15 digits, you're in for a **world of pain** if you try to program the application in Javascript. If you can, avoid it.

Comment: @robertklep How can I even perform like this becoze some is sending the data as very big number so how can I pass this as a sttring

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI see my edit. You probably have to specifically enable `BIGINT` support in the MySQL driver.

Comment: @robertklep So I have to change the sql package for supportig the very big numbers

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI no, you have to set the correct option. It already supports big numbers, but that support is disabled by default. Please read the documentation.